# The terminal crash on my little program

Tags: c, codeblocks

When i try to execute this little program on the while my terminal crash and i don't know why! Somebody can help me? =) The problem is in the while. My colpiler (code:blocks) doesn't say anything O_o just one warning, but no errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define mxl 30

typedef struct inc{
int ora;
char desc[mxl];
} incluso;

typedef struct dati {
char data[mxl];
int n_a;
incluso *a;
} agenda;

int main(){
FILE *f;
agenda *p;
int i,orai,oraf;
char c, datar[mxl],nomefile[mxl],datapp[mxl];

printf("Inserisci il nome del file: ");
scanf("%s",&nomefile);

f=fopen(nomefile,"r");
if(f==NULL){
    printf("Impossibile aprire il file!");
    exit(1);
    }
    else{
    printf("Inserisci data, ora inizio ed ora fine nel formato gg/mm hh hh: ");
    scanf("%s %d %d",datar, orai,oraf);

    while((c=getc(f))!=EOF){
        if(fscanf(f,"%s",&datapp)==datar){
        fscanf(f,"%s",&p->data);
        fscanf(f,"%d",&p->n_a);
        p->a=(incluso*)malloc(p->n_a*sizeof(incluso));
        for(i=0;i<p->n_a;i++){
                fscanf(f,"%d",&p->a[i].ora);
                fscanf(f,"%s",&p->a[i].desc);
            }
        }
    }

    for(i<0;i<p->n_a;i++){
        if(p->a[i].ora>orai && p->a[i].ora<oraf )
            printf("%s %d %s", p->data, p->a[i].ora, p->a[i].desc);
    }

    free(p->a);
    fclose(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet that warning is the actual problem.

Comment: Im am not sure what is actually causing segfaults in your program, but I see at least two problems with your code: `1.) You are reading strings without telling scanf maximum capacity, you should use "%30s" format specifier or similar (else a malicious user or garbled input might crash your program)` `2.) Your malloc/free calls seems to be unbalanced, i.e. you are calling malloc several times in a loop, but you have only one free`

Comment: C:\Users\Alessandro\Desktop\main.c|35|warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]|

Comment: Aniway yes, i've to balance the malloc =) But with some printf i've seen that program crashes on while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems as follows my noticed...

change

`scanf("%s %d %d",datar, orai,oraf);`

to

`scanf("%s %d %d",datar, &orai, &oraf);`

and

```
fscanf(f,"%s",&p->data);
```

to

```
p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
...
fscanf(f,"%s", p->data);
```

---

ADD

```
if(fscanf(f,"%s",&datapp)==datar){
```

Probably

```
if(fscanf(f, "%s", datapp)==1){
```

Comment: The same... anyway don't go :( it crashs

Comment: @user3182783 There are other problems. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what BLUEPIXY already mentioned:

```
scanf("%s",&nomefile);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s",nomefile);
```

because `nomefile` is an array and is reduced to a pointer already.

```
if(fscanf(f,"%s",&datapp)==datar){
```

Same here. It should be:

```
if(fscanf(f,"%s",datapp)==datar){
```

Also what do you want to compare here? The left side is an `int` and the right side a `char*`. If you want to compare the strings you have to do it in an extra line and with `strcmp`: (You also need to `#include <string.h>` for this)

```
fscanf(f,"%s",datapp);
if(strcmp(datapp, datar) == 0){
```

The same problem again:

```
                fscanf(f,"%s",&p->a[i].desc);
```

should be

```
                fscanf(f,"%s",p->a[i].desc);
```

Here you probably have a typo:

```
 for(i<0;i<p->n_a;i++){
```

should be

```
 for(i=0;i<p->n_a;i++){
```

With all warnings activated (`-Wall -Wextra`) gcc warned me for each of these.

Also (but there is no warning for this) you are repeatedly allocating for `p->a`. This should be done only once before the loop. Don't forget to free `p` either.

Comment: ok so i add this on my compiler, i try and let you know, thank you!

Comment: @user3182783 I only went through the warnings and haven't looked at your overall code yet.

Comment: @user3182783 Do you know how the debugger works? You should use it to find the exact condition resulting in the error. Then you can ask for it here. Most people don't have interest and time to test your code. Also we don not know the file input and cannot simulate it.

Comment: ok i'll learn how to use the debugger, sorry if it was a problem i was just asking =)

Comment: I've used debugger and it shows me the adderesses of the stack but i don't know how to find the problem :S

Comment: Anyway i've found a segmentation fault error (with the debugger) but i don't understand the problem..

Comment: @user3182783 It also shows you the line in your code producing the error. Tell us where it is and with which input it happens

Comment: no he shows me the memory address but not the line... infact when i click on jump on the line it does nothing...

Comment: it give me a problem about a dll, the ntdll.dll for the istance